# Kernel not loading | Custom OS

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, osdev

I'm trying to make a kernel for an operating system I'm trying to make, however, it seems the kernel isn't being loaded since the kernel is not printing anything like it should

Error I get when using gdb:

> During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

I know the code is kind of bad, I'm planning to fix and tidy it up once this works.
This is my code:

kernel/main.cpp:

```
extern "C" void kernelMain() {
    const char* welcome = "Welcome to the kernel!";
    char* videoMemory = (char*) 0xb8000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 80*25; i++) {
        videoMemory[i*2] = ' ';
        videoMemory[i*2+1] = 0x0f;
    }

    for (int i = 0; welcome[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        videoMemory[i*2] = welcome[i];
    }
}

extern "C" void _start() {
    kernelMain();
    while (1) {}
}
```

kernel/linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

boot/boot.asm:

```
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    mov si, msg
    call print

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 0x06
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov bx, 0x1000
    int 0x13

    jmp 0x1000

print:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07
    mov al, [si]
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 0x10
    inc si
    jmp print

.done:
    ret

msg db "Loading Bootloader...", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Makefile:

```
NASM=nasm
QEMU=qemu-system-x86_64
CC=gcc
LD=ld

all: boot.bin kernel.bin

boot.bin: boot/boot.asm
    $(NASM) -f bin $< -o $@

kernel.bin: kernel/main.cpp kernel/linker.ld
    $(CC) -ffreestanding -c $< -o kernel.o
    $(LD) -o $@ -T kernel/linker.ld kernel.o

run: boot.bin kernel.bin
    $(QEMU) -drive format=raw,file=boot.bin

clean:
    rm -f boot.bin kernel.bin kernel.o
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code where you switch to protected mode? Is your gcc 32 bit? Also your boot sector does not initialize segment registers.

Comment: I was going to enter protected mode once I got the kernel loaded, is it needed to do that before hand?

Comment: Once you got the kernel loaded, but before you transfer control to it for obvious reasons. Also you just randomly jump to `0x1000` which is most probably not `_start` but if you are lucky it will at least be `kernelMain`.